# The inverse of the integration over a ball with radius $\epsilon$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, probability-theory

First of all sorry for the nondescript title, but this seemed like the most suitable one.

Now let $d\geq2, D\subset \mathbb{R}$ a domain and $G:D\times D\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ continuous. Define 
$$G_\epsilon(x,y):=\int_{B(x,r)}G(z,y) dz, \text{ for } B(y,\epsilon) \subset D \text{ and } x \in D.$$

Where B(x,r) is the ball with radius r and $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue measure.
Now the problematic part:
$$G(x,y)=\lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \frac{1}{\mathcal{L}(B(y,\epsilon))}G_\epsilon (x,y)$$

This is part of a prove to show that G has the middle value property and at this point it has already been proven for $G_\epsilon$. To me it looks like a general rule and is not dependent on the particular function, but I couldn't find or remember anything resembling this, so maybe I'm mistaken.
Either way I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: If $G$ is continuous (and $D$ is open), this is easy. In general, you should maybe look at the **Lebesgue differentiation theorem**.

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.